# spam email forwarding by server

Tags: email, spam

Let's start with this scenario:

> We have a mailbox (i.e. in yahoo), every message is sent by this
>   account, marked as spam by Gmail spam filter. (because the address or
>   sender IP is blacklisted, not because of content)
>
> There is a server which is able to forward incoming messages to
>   another address (email forwarding), for example, to a Gmail mailbox.
>   And it is not blacklisted.

**The question is**: If we send a message, through the dirty mailbox to the server, and server forward it to a Gmail mailbox, will it marked as spam by spam filters?

Comment: Ask the google people

Comment: You should read  ["Best practices for forwarding mail to Gmail"](https://support.google.com/a/answer/175365?hl=en)..

Answer (score 1):

## Perhaps...

It might, or it might not.  Or it might sometimes and not other times.

Only fixing the root cause will result in a lasting fix.  You would probably want to find out what is actually causing the deliverability problem, before even trying to speculate on what might be a solution.

You assume that it is IP reputation and not content. It could be, or it could not be. It could be the user's choice. It could actually be your content after all. It could be an issue of behavior, such as spamming. It could be a bug in Gmail's filters. It could be your domain. It could be a domain in a URL in the message body. It could be any number of, or even combination of, factors.

Try to find the actual problem, rather than guessing. That will make solving the problem almost infinitely easier.

So, will your proposed solution work? Maybe.